# Understanding more about synchronizing a class itself

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
    StaticThreadTest st = new StaticThreadTest();
    StaticThreadTest st1 = new StaticThreadTest();
    st.threadNew.start();
    st1.incrementer.start();

    synchronized (StaticThreadTest.class) {...}
```

In **para 1**, different threads are running on different instance of class. In **para 2** synchronizing happens on Class itself. As we learned, if the Class.class is in synchronization block, there should be just a single instance of the `Class` object accessed by all threads. And it contradicts with, different threads for different instance concept in para 1.

Please help me know, how this actually works ?

Comment: `there should be just a single instance of the class accessed by all threads` That is meaningless and false.

Comment: There is a single instance of a Class object (`StaticThreadTest.class`) per ClassLoader.  I think that's what they are trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

The `synchronized` block will prevent two threads from running code simultaneously, as long as both blocks are synchronized on the same object.
Instead, the second thread will wait for the first one to finish.

If you synchronize on a `Something.class` literal, you are guaranteed to be using the same instance, since `X.class` will always have the same value.

Comment: `X.class` will always have the same value in the same `ClassLoader`.

Comment: but in the above code snippet only one theard will access the synchronized block and the threads created will not have any affect on the code in para 2 isnt it?